# SafeConfigParser.read() with file object instead of string

Tags: python, configparser, python-click

I'm using [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) to pass in an argument that is a file name. This file name is meant to be used by `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser.read()` to read an ini file. Unfortunately, Click passes in a file object which `read()` cannot handle.

Is there a way to allow `read()` to take a file object or can Click be configured to not open the file (but still do the checks)?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I found out that `ConfigParser` has a method for reading file handles specifically. It is called `readfp(self, fp, filename=None)`. This if probably a better answer. I'll leave my old answer below, if someone should be interested in that solution.

You can get the filename from the filehandle using the `name` property. This can be passed to `ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser.read()`.

Small example just printing out the filename:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('filehandle', type=click.File('rb'))
def print_filename(filehandle):
    print "File name: %s" % filehandle.name

if __name__=="__main__":
    print_filename()
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution for which the file doesn't need to be opened twice.

Comment: I just saw that `ConfigParser` has a method for reading file handles specifically. It is called `readfp(self, fp, filename=None)`. It does not open the file, so it should work.